# Scala Akka Type unspecified value parameters

Tags: scala, list, akka

I have a REST App in Akka and Scala
there is Path AddToBasket with ID I want to add a Product from a Product list to a BasketList so a Customer can add a Product to his basket. My Problem is

```
~(path("AddToBasket" / IntNumber) & post) { number =>
  //I get the selected Product with Product id
  val product1 = Product.PRODUCT_LIST.find(_.id == number)
  if (product1.isDefined) {
    println(product1.toString())

    //here I want to add the found product to the Basket
    //but always an unspecified value parameters error
    basket ! AddToBasket(Product(product1))
    complete(Basket.BASKET_LIST ::= product1)

  } else complete("Not Found ")
  println(Basket.BASKET_LIST.toString())
  complete(s"Added Product ${product1} to Basket")
}
```

There is an object Basket which has an empty BASKET_LIST [Product]

```
object Basket {
  var BASKET_LIST = List.empty[Product]

  def apply(basketId: Int, customerRef: ActorRef)(
      implicit system: ActorSystem): ActorRef =
    system.actorOf(Props(classOf[Basket], basketId, customerRef))

  case class AddToBasket(product: Product)    
}
```

So my Question is how can I receive a Product with id and add it to the basket list?

Comment: instead of `basket ! AddToBasket(Product(product1))`, remove `Product` and do `basket ! AddToBasket(product1)`. can you share the specific exception?

Comment: Yes thanks but when I try add to basket(product) is the same it says the parameters expected do not match

Comment: what is the type of `product1` ?  maybe the type of `Product` which defines at `Basket` is from another class? (same name but different package?)

Comment: Error:(135, 28) value ::= is not a member of List[eu.isic.akka.restserver.Product]
  Expression does not convert to assignment because:
    type mismatch;
     found   : Option[eu.isic.akka.restserver.Product]
     required: eu.isic.akka.restserver.Product
    expansion: basket.BASKET_LIST = basket.BASKET_LIST.::(product1)
        basket.BASKET_LIST ::= product1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this error because `find` returns an `Option[Product]`.
What you need to do is -

```
product1.foreach{product => 
    basket ! AddToBasket(product)
    complete(Basket.BASKET_LIST ::= product)
}
```

`foreach` takes out the `Option` and give you the product instance (if exists).

Comment: Yes that was it the foreach was taking out the Option and gave me the product instance. MAny thanks. Perfect ;)